# What is a word that means rough times of change?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Like for example when two regimes change there is this unrest and change that occurs. Often it isn’t meant in a positive light and simply means that things are beginning to change. It is just when that change occurs people often say this word.

I have a feeling the word I’m thinking starts with an R. Please help because I’ve been browsing the internet for hours and haven’t been able to find a synonym or closely related word that would fit.

Comment: here is a sentence...     “the state of Palestine Is in....(word)”. Upheaval, tumult would be close synonyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "**regime change**" is fully appropriate, especially if prefaced with "**chaotic**" or "**tumultuous**." Maybe consider "**interregnum**." As Sabir suggested, "**upheaval**" is also appropriate, or "**instability**."

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as if you are describing a commonly use term, Sabir, but none come to mind except 'revolution.' But that also is used for long-term processes, and not short-term transitions. Other possibilities: disarray, transition, flux, chaos, and reconstruction.

Answer (score 3):

Revolution, revolt, or rebellion? Restlessness is another.

Answer (score 0):

"in a state of unrest"